# iPhone Saved Pop Up

Tags: iphone, popup

Does anyone know if the popup in the attached screenshot is standard in the SDK? I'm trying to figure out how to make it and don't really want to start from scratch.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not standard in the SDK (actually it is, but it's private so you can't use it in AppStore apps).

However, there's a lot of open source components that do exactly that.

My favourite is [SVProgressHUD](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD), but a popular alternative is [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD).

Comment: Sweet! SVProgressHUD worked amazingly well... quick question: can you set a short delay in between the "show" and "dismiss" so the activity indicator has time to show?

Comment: As Jack said you can use an NSTimer, but I find `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` more convenient.